# UNIQUE constraint failed: Student_assignments.user_id

Tags: django

I am trying to achieve that  Student is Connected to User Assignment is Connected to Student.

Django Migrations Issue.

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: Student_student.user_id

models.py file

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator,MaxValueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,default=111111)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    student_address = models.TextField()
    student_bloodgrp = models.CharField(max_length = 3)
    #This will be used to upload image of student in some directory not in database
    student_image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='profile_pic/')
    student_mail = models.EmailField()
    student_dob = models.DateTimeField()
    student_branch = models.CharField(max_length = 3)
    student_reg_no = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999999999)])
    student_mob = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999999999)])
    student_sem = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(8)])
    student_accom = models.CharField(max_length = 1) # y for boarders & n for non-boarders

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Students"







class Subjects(models.Model):
    subjectName = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    semester = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Subjects"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subjectName+"--"+self.branch+"--"+str(self.semester)


class Assignments(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subjects,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='assignments/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Assignments"



    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.student_name
```

forms.py here

```
forms.py  


from django import forms
from .models import Assignments


class AssignmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Assignments
        fields = ('student', 'document','subject' )


    ******************************************************************
views.py here 

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import AssignmentForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def mainStudent(request):

    return render(request,'Student/main.html')


def masterStudent(request):

    return render(request,'Student/master.html')



@login_required
def uploadAssignment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AssignmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('student-main')
    else:
        form =AssignmentForm()


    return render(request, 'Student/upload_Assignment.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

I want that Student User Id and Password is connected to User .
Assignment 1st field to be Student .

Answer (score 0):

You're using a default value for your `OneToOneField` which doesn't really make sense. Using a `OneToOneField` means you can only have one `Student` record per `User`. The default will work the first time a `Student` is created without a `User`, but the next time it will fail with a unique constraint error. The migrations are probably trying to add more than one `Student` record without a `User`.

You should remove the default value and examine your data to understand where the `Student`s without `User`s are coming from. Alternatively, you could make the `user` field nullable and remove the `primary_key=True` so that Django creates an implicit `id` primary key:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```